# How to plot a 3d surface plot using plotly in R?

Tags: r, plot, plotly

I have a following dataset:

```
group<-c(rep("X1",5),rep("X3",5))
set.seed(1)
value<-c(seq(0.2, 1, .2),seq(10, 30, 5))
time<-c("2018-07-01 00:00:00","2018-07-01 01:00:00","2018-07-01 02:00:00","2018-07-01 03:00:00","2018-07-01 04:00:00",
        "2018-07-01 00:00:00","2018-07-01 01:00:00","2018-07-01 03:00:00","2018-07-01 04:00:00","2018-07-01 05:00:00")
order<-c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,4,5,6)
country<-c("HU","ZA","XX","ZZ","RO","HU","ZA","XX","ZZ","RO")
dat <-data.frame(time,country,group,value,order)
```

I want to plot a 3d plot where `x=order, Y=value, z=hour(time)`. I read here that z should have dimension [x,y].
[3d Surface Plot in R with plotly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47439160/3d-surface-plot-in-r-with-plotly)
4
Something like this one should be obtained:

[image]

How can I plot this, because do not understand how can I create a matrix for Z with this dimension?

Answer (score 2):

Your data doesn't seem suited for 3D. You can't have two values for z with the same x and y-axis. If you filter out one of the groups you can technically make it work, but I think some other chart would work better. Here's an example of how you could make it work with one group and an example of a plot that may work better.

```
library(plotly)

group<-c(rep("X1",5),rep("X3",5))
set.seed(1)
value<-c(seq(0.2, 1, .2),seq(10, 30, 5))
time<-c("2018-07-01 00:00:00","2018-07-01 01:00:00","2018-07-01 02:00:00","2018-07-01 03:00:00","2018-07-01 04:00:00",
        "2018-07-01 00:00:00","2018-07-01 01:00:00","2018-07-01 03:00:00","2018-07-01 04:00:00","2018-07-01 05:00:00")
order<-c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,4,5,6)
country<-c("HU","ZA","XX","ZZ","RO","HU","ZA","XX","ZZ","RO")
dat <-data.frame(time,country,group,value,order)

library(tidyverse)
m = dat %>%
  filter(group == "X1") %>% 
  pivot_wider(c(time,value,order), names_from = time,
                    values_from = value) %>% 
  select(-order) %>%
  as.matrix
m[] = case_when(is.na(m) ~ 0, TRUE ~ m)
plot_ly(z = ~m) %>% 
  add_surface()

plot_ly(data = dat, x = ~time, y = ~value, color = ~group)
```

This is an example of data that is better suited

```
m = matrix(rnorm(25),nrow = 5, ncol = 5)

plot_ly(z = ~m) %>% 
  add_surface()
```

Comment: Thank you! could you also i.e. create a sample data, which produces the same plot with the same axis's as in my picture (numbers can be random)? I.e. If I have hourly data for X variables (numeric) for 5 years (say there is only one group). How can I plot this surface plot where X=values, Y=years, Z=Months ? (should I group by months and years and aggregate by mean(values) in order to plot it?

Comment: I would aggregate by month. Look into how to do that with lubridate. This sample data switches months and values, but is basically what  you would want to do and how I would label it. ```library(plotly)
library(tidyverse)

dat = matrix(rnorm(24*60),ncol=24,nrow = 60)
plot_ly(z = ~dat) %>% 
  add_surface() %>% 
  layout(scene = list(xaxis = list(title = "hours"),
                      yaxis = list(title = "months"),
                      zaxis = list(title = "value")))```